# React native firebase analytics not saving specific user property

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-analytics

I have a react-native app.
I'm using `react-native-firebase`'s analytics module for 4 months successfully to log some events. [Here](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/analytics/reference/analytics) you can find the doc

Now I want to save some user properties with the `setUserProperty` method and I am currently testing the thing in the firebase DebugView.

I'm correctly logging screen views, events and user properties except for one single property.
Here is a screen from the DebugView:
[image: DebugView screenshot]

Here is the code where I fire the `voucher_redeemed_event`:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (!prevProps.successMessage && !!this.props.successMessage) {
    firebase.analytics().logEvent('voucher_redeemed_event');
    firebase.analytics().setUserProperty('user_redemed_voucher', 'true');
  }
}
```

Why is the user property not logged?
I get all the other properies correctly (there are way less than the 25 limit).
It is not a question of time, I've waited for 10 minutes without results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"

Seems that a simple restart of the app and a coffee cup can solve this problem

Comment: What the benefits of using firebase analytics in RN In particular

Comment: I've integrated firebase to receive remote push notifications and track crashes so without adding other SDKs you can have a free solution to track events and user properties. Recently you can also visualize all the data in google analytics

Comment: Hmm Well, have u an article or something for track crashes use firebase analytics in react native?

Comment: I use Crashlytics module of `react-native-firebase`. You have to integrate the whole framework (https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/getting-started) and then install the Crashlytics module. I remember it was a pain but I made it work somehow. I've also updated the app (originally 0.56 to 0.59) recently and still work